# How do I marshal a pointer to a series of null-terminated strings in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

I need some help with the following. I've got a c++ API (no access to source) and I'm struggling with the methods returning char* attributes, or returned structures containing char* attributes. According to the API's documentation the return value is as follows:

Return Values
If the function succeeds, the return value is a pointer to a series of null-terminated strings, one for each project on the host system, ending with a second null character. The following example shows the buffer contents with `<null>` representing the terminating null character:

```
project1<null>project2<null>project3<null><null>
```

If the function fails, the return value is NULL

The problem I'm having is that the returned pointer in C# only contains the first value... project1 in this case. How can I get the full list to be able to loop through them on the managed side?

Here's the c# code:

> ```
>     [DllImport("vmdsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DSGetProjectList", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
>     public static extern IntPtr DSGetProjectList();
> ```

Calling method:

> ```
>    IntPtr ptrProjectList = DSAPI.DSGetProjectList();
>    string strProjectList = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrProjectList).ToString();
> ```

strProjectList only contains the first item.
Here's the info from the API's header file...

> ```
>    DllImport char *DSGetProjectList dsproto((void));
> ```

Here's some sample code from a c++ console app which I've used for testing purposes...

> ```
>    char *a;
>    a = DSGetProjectList( );
>    while( *a ) { 
>     printf("a=%s\n", a); 
>     a += 1 + strlen(a); 
>    }
> ```

Each iteration correctly displays every project in the list.

Comment: You should give at least the signature of the C++ API you used, and maybe a bit of the C# code that is calling this API.

Comment: Please add your c# code that is calling the c++ api

Comment: Dis you carefully check the result (Length) ?

Comment: If you know C/C++, you can find all required tools for working with unmanaged memory, in the `Marshal` class, look at the methods: `AllocHGlobal`, `FreeHGlobal`, `Copy` overloads, `StringToPtr*`, `PtrToString*` and others. `Marshal` class + `IntPtr` structure allow to reproduce any C/C++ memory management tricks in C# code.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post with some code that I'm currently using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when converting the C++ char* to a C# string using `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`, it stops at the first null character.

**You shouldn't convert directly the `char*` to a string.**

You could copy the `char*` represented by an `IntPtr` to a `byte[]` using `Marshal.Copy` and then extract as many string as necessary (see [*Matthew Watson*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16059344/1439688) for extracting strings from a managed array), but you'll need to get the multi-string size first.

As *leppie* suggest you can also extract the first string using `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` then increment the pointer by this string size and extract the next string and so on. You stops when is extracts an empty string (from the last NULL character).

Something like :

```
IntPtr ptrProjectList = DSAPI.DSGetProjectList();
List<string> data;
string buffer;
do {
    buffer = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrProjectList);
    ptrProjectList += buffer.size() + 1;
    data.Add(buffer);
}while(buffer.size() > 0)
```

Comment: And when it stops, why not just increment the pointer with `strlen + 1`?

Comment: Yes that's another possibility but he has to carefully stops at the right time, maybe looping over a managed array is easiest for a C# programmer.

Comment: zakinster... you're the man. Thanks everyone for your help and the quick responses. It's working 100%. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of string is called a `Multi-String`, and it's quite common in the Windows API.

Marshaling them is fiddly. What you have to do is marshal it as a `char[]` array, rather than a string, and then convert the `char[]` array to a set of strings.

[See here for an example solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268899/how-do-you-convert-multistring-to-from-c-sharp-string-collection). I've copied the relevant code into this answer, but it is copied from the link I gave:

```
static List<string> MultiStringToList(char[] multistring)
{
    var stringList = new List<string>();
    int i = 0;

    while (i < multistring.Length)
    {
        int j = i;

        if (multistring[j++] == '\0') 
            break;

        while (j < multistring.Length)
        {
            if (multistring[j++] == '\0')
            {
                stringList.Add(new string(multistring, i, j - i - 1));
                i = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return stringList;
}
```